# Shell programming error

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I'm new to shell programming and I'm supposed to do this

1. Create two directories OS_filesR and OS_filesW on Desktop
2. Ask the user to enter file name.
3. Create file with the entered file name in OS_filesR if this is the Odd Creation and
   remove readable permission.
   If this is the even Creation, Create the file in OS_filesW and remove writable
   permission.
4. Ask user if he/she wants to create another file if yes repeat steps (2, 3), if no
   exist.

Here is the code:

```
mkdir /home/karim/Desktop/OS_filesR /home/karim/Desktop/OS_filesW

counter=0

while(1)
do
        echo "Enter the file name"
        read var
        if[$counter % 2 -eq 0]
        then
                touch /home/karim/Desktop/OS_filesW/$var
                chmod -w $var
        else
                touch /home/karim/Desktop/OS_filesR/$var
                chmod -r $var
        fi
        echo "Do you want to create another file? Enter yes or no"
        read var2
        if[$var2 != "yes"]
        then
                break
        fi

        counter++
done
```

I keep getting this error:

line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
line 9:`   then'

So how can I fix this?

Comment: You may find [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) useful

Answer (score 1):

Place a space after the "[" on line 9.   "[" is just an alias for the test command, and is not parsed separately from the rest of the string without the space.

Comment: Please vote to close questions that are clearly duplicates rather than posting answers to them.